# PHP array (not accepting function?)

Tags: php, arrays, oop

So I'm trying to learn OOP in PHP deeper by making a simple lexer. But I've come to a problem with OOP that I can't seem to resolve. I'm using arrays instead of Enumerations here.

```
<?php
class Lexer {
    private static $type = [
        "none" => 0,
        "int"  => 1
    ];

    private static $tokens = [
        TokenData("WHITESPACE", "\s+", $type['none']),
        TokenData("NUMBER", "[0-9]+", $type['int'])
    ];

    public function __construct($source) {
        return $this->Tokenize($source);
    }

    private function Tokenize($source) {
        return self::$tokens;
    }

    public function TokenData($name, $pattern, $type) {
        return array("name" => $name, "pattern" => $pattern, "type" => self::$type[$type]);
    }

    private function Token($return) {
        return self::$tokens[$return];
    }
}
?>
```

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in ...
>   on line 9

I've tried `$this->TokenData(...)` and also `self::$type[...]` but none of these worked. Is there anything else I'm missing?

I'm expecting the result to be something like this:

```
$tokens = array(
  0 => array("WHITESPACE", "\s+", $type['none']),
  1 => array("NUMBER", "[0-9]+", $type['int'])
)
```

Comment: Static properties must be constant values, not expressions.

Comment: why on earth are these statics anyway?